# How to initialize an array and pass it as an argument without declaring it?

Tags: c++

How to initialize an array and pass it as an argument without declaring it? I'd like to write the following in one line without using the intermediate array `color`.

```
unsigned char color[3] = {100, 20, 0};
paintWithColor(color);
```

The function is declared as `void paintWithColor( const unsigned char* )`.
The following does not work:

```
paintWithColor({100,20,0});
```

I'm sorry if I got any terms wrong.

Comment: You may want to use a [`std::array<char,3>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to achieve this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks. I'm not in charge of the paintWithColor signature, would it be cast automatically?

Comment: @ilent2 I'm using Visual C++ 2013 and don't know which features it supports.

Answer (score 2):

With C++11 you might use an overload taking an initializer list:

```
#include <iostream>

void paintWithColor(const unsigned char* ) {
    std::cout << "Painting\n";
}
void paintWithColor(std::initializer_list<unsigned char> colors) {
    paintWithColor(colors.begin());
}

int main()
{
    paintWithColor({100,20,0});
}
```

Note: This works with MSVC 2013 (See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/02/c-11-14-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp.aspx)